# Highchart Data Series Column Total but Space

Tags: highcharts, series, highcharts-ng, stacking-context

Please help me ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobks.png)

My JSON Data:
{
"name": "PAKET BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING",
"id": "PAKET BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING",
"dataLabels": {
"enabled": false
},
"data": [
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
570
],
[
"5 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
114
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
228
],
[
"3 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
76
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
1040
],
[
"20 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
52
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
1368
],
[
"2 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
684
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
360
],
[
"15 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
24
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
120
],
[
"12 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
10
],
[
"BRIGHTY GLOWING UNDERARM (PO100RB)",
1020
],
[
"10 BRIGHTY UNDERARM GLOWING (BR9)",
102
]
]
}

Comment: There is a problem with your question - there is no question.

Comment: Hi @Syadhaffa Gedriyansah, Please provide a more detailed description of the problem. I have created a live example with your data here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/654bmpuc/ You can update it to show the issue.